# facing error as "This session is not valid for use with the REST API" while integration with PHP platform

Tags: rest-api, api, integration

I want to create lead record using integration of php platform. I have written rest API for that. The code is working fine when tested on workbench. But now I have integrated salesforce with PHP platform. I do recieved the correct access code,client_id,client_secret,username,password, security token,Authorization:OAuth . I am sending the response in JSON format. But I am facing the issue like :

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [message] => This session is not valid for use with the REST API
            [errorCode] => INVALID_SESSION_ID
        )
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: How are you authenticating and getting a Session ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David Reed, yes i am getting session ID.
Actually  I had missed two factor authentication setting in session setting.Now the error is solved.